# Capture picture through Camera API 2 and save it as a Bitmap

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, camera

I am working on an app that uses a camera to take  a picture then show it in another activity, I have tried the following code

```
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
        Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, null);
        SetBitmap setBitmap = new SetBitmap();
        setBitmap.setMbitmap(myBitmap);
        image.close();
    }
```

after this I get my bitmap in the other activity like this

```
    myBitmap = CamActivity.setBitmap.getMbitmap();
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

SetBitmap is a class that sets the bitmap

I have a button to capture cam when I click on it , it suppose to take a picture and start another activity to show the image but it crashes then
So what can I do now I am starting my activity in a wrong way?or the issue is with bitmap?
this is the error log

```
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.camtest/com.example.android.camtest.DisplayActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap com.example.android.camtest.SetBitmap.getMbitmap()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap com.example.android.camtest.SetBitmap.getMbitmap()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.android.camtest.DisplayActivity.onCreate(DisplayActivity.java:37)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 

                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.media.ImageReader$ListenerHandler) {b9cb033} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                                           at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(Handler.java:534)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessage(Handler.java:519)
                                                                           at android.media.ImageReader.postEventFromNative(ImageReader.java:511)
                                                                           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.nativeProduceFrame(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.produceFrame(LegacyCameraDevice.java:516)
                                                                           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager$2.onPictureTaken(RequestThreadManager.java:224)
                                                                           at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1142)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.CameraDeviceUserShim$CameraLooper.run(CameraDeviceUserShim.java:144)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

this is where I take the picture

```
private void takePic() {
    if (cameraDevice == null)
        return;
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
        Size[] jpegSizes = null;
        if (characteristics != null)
            jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                    .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

        int width = 700;
        int height = 600;

        if (jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0) {
            width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
            height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
        }
        final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
        List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
        outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
        outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));


        String fileName = "IMG_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss").format(new Date()) + ".jpg";

        File captureDirectory = new File("/Download");

        if (!captureDirectory.isDirectory()) captureDirectory.mkdirs();
        final File mediaFile = new File(captureDirectory, fileName);

        final Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                "com.mydomain.fileprovider",
                mediaFile);


        ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {

                Image mImage = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
                ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                buffer.get(bytes);
                try {
                    save(bytes);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                OutputStream output = null;
                try {
                    output = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri);
                    output.write(bytes);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    mImage.close();
                    if (output != null) {
                        try {
                            output.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }


            }

            private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                OutputStream output = null;
                try {
                    output = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
                    output.write(bytes);
                } finally {
                    if (output != null)
                        output.close();
                }

            }
        };
        Intent displayIntent = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
        displayIntent.putExtra("FILE_URI", fileUri);

        Log.e("uri", fileUri + "");


        startActivity(displayIntent);

        reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);

        final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                Toast.makeText(CamActivity.this, "Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };


    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is the Display activity

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    bundleExtras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundleExtras != null){
        Uri savedBitmapUri = bundleExtras.getParcelable("FILE_URI");
        imageView.setImageURI(savedBitmapUri);
        Log.e("uri",savedBitmapUri+"");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "null pic", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

file provider

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="myDownloads" path="Download" />
<root-path name="sdcard1" path="." /> </paths>
```

Comment: Can you post your error logs ?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava sure I updated my question

Comment: Try the solution posted

Answer (score 3):

Your approach to passing bitmap data to another activity is wrong. First of all, you should check [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). When you start different Activity, let's call it B from A, the A Activity will be destroyed and all resources will be destroyed. On the Android Activity LifeCycle documentation, they mentioned this:

> The onDestroy() callback releases all resources that have not yet been
>   released by earlier callbacks such as onStop().

So, you cannot access the variables after activity destroyed. What you should do is, you should save the bitmap to the file and pass the file URI via the intent extra and get the URI from another activity's onCreate callback.

You can use FileProvider to save the file, and pass the provider URI via intent which is the best "***Android kind***" approach, or you can save the file's path to the shared preferences, and read it from another activity which is not stable and not the best practice.

Let's use FileProvider: 
You can check the [Android Documentation about FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#ProviderDefinition) to define it.

```
// Assume that you added Captures path to your FileProvider's paths.
// Create temporary image file.
String fileName = "IMG_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss").format(new Date()) + ".jpg";  
File captureDirectory = new File(getFilesDir(), "Captures");
if( !captureDirectory.isDirectory() ) captureDirectory.mkdirs();
File mediaFile = new File(captureDirectory, fileName);

Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.mydomain.fileprovider",
                    mediaFile);  

// Save the Bitmap.
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
    Image mImage = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
    ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    buffer.get(bytes);
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri);
        output.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        mImage.close();
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Pass the file uri via intent.
Intent displayIntent = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
displayIntent.putExtra("FILE_URI", mediaFile);
startActivity(displayIntent);

// Read the uri from started activity and show the bitmap
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    ... 
    bundleExtras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundleExtras != null){
        Uri savedBitmapUri = bundleExtras.getParcelable("FILE_URI");
        mImageView_Preview.setImageURI(savedBitmapUri);
    }
    else{
        // Uri not inside the intent data.
    }
    ...
}
```

You should not load all bytes to the memory as a Bitmap. You can just save the captured image to the file and pass its file Uri created from your application's FileProvider and show the file Uri with one line code.

Basic optimizations: 
 - You can create the file in the cache directory
 - You can remove the file after completing your task with using [FileProvider
   permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#Permissions).
 - You can do the saving job on the background thread like Google did in [android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample. 
 - And more...

Comment: I really tried sending bitmap by intent but not in this way, I will try this out,Thanks a lot for our help

Comment: I did this way, you can checkout my project: https://github.com/birfincankafein/customcamera

Comment: I tried this method but its not showing the image when I launch my activity , its not saving picture at the device is this the reason why there is no image in the new activity?

Comment: Can you give any logcat output? I think problem related with something different because Im using this method to save image show in a different activity on my Camera2 api project.

Comment: Uri savedUri = bundleExtras.getParcelable("FILE_URI");
I logged this  then   Log.e("uri",savedUri+""); 
I got this log   com.example.android.camtest E/uri: null Uri 
 sorry if I am troubling you, I really appreciate your help

Comment: Are you sure that you put uri into the intent extra as I wrote? 
    Intent displayIntent = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
    displayIntent.putExtra("FILE_URI", mediaFile);
    startActivity(displayIntent);

Comment: Yes, I did the same

Comment: I have to check your code. I created a chatroom for this but your reputation is not enough to write access. You should share more code. I need to check the new version. Can you update the question and add new code ?

Comment: I did updated my question, thanks again for your concern

Comment: I checked it , its not triggered

Comment: you should focus on this issue. The problem is not related with uri or bitmap I think the problem is image save callback never triggering. You should find out why it's not triggering.